# SIP Asterisk CLI commands from android application

Tags: android, command-line-interface, sip, asterisk

Is there a way to send commands from an Android application to Asterisk CLI? Something like this: 'sip show peers' to see which users are online and offline. Maybe there is another way to check users registration status and show it in an Android app? Any ideas?

Comment: Use the Asterisk Manager Interface and send a `SIPpeers` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have two easy options for that.  The first is have your Asterisk web-enabled and then make REST calls to it from a browser app.  Alternately, you can get a few nice SSH/TTY clients for Android that will let you connect to your Asterisk server.  I do this with my Android ICS tablet.